# How to display pop up message on top of selected text in any website?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension, popup

I am working on a chrome extension where I need to display a pop-up on the selection of text on any website just like the image attached below.(Similar example is implemented [here](https://github.com/pnlpal/dictionariez)).

Though I am able to read the content and position, I am not displaying pop-up at the right position. Any help would be appreciated.

Here is the snippet :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <title>Custom menu on text selection</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pro.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.10.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-AYmEC3Yw5cVb3ZcuHtOA93w35dYTsvhLPVnYs9eStHfGJvOvKxVfELGroGkvsg+p" crossorigin="anonymous" />
        <style>
            .menu {
                display: none;
                position: absolute;
                background: #a4a4a4;
                border-radius: 6px;
            }
        </style>

        <script>
            var pageX, pageY;
            document.addEventListener("mouseup", () => {
                if (document.querySelector(".menu") != null) {
                    document.querySelector(".menu").remove();
                }
                let selection = document.getSelection();
                let selectedText = selection.toString();
                //this div will diplay in popup
                var iDiv = document.createElement("div");
                iDiv.className = "menu";
                iDiv.innerHTML = '<i class="fa fa-copy fa-2x" id="copy-btn"></i>';
                document.body.appendChild(iDiv);
                var menu = document.querySelector(".menu");

                //if the text is not empty show dialog
                if (selectedText !== "") {
                    var range = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
                    let rect = range.getBoundingClientRect();
                    menu.style.display = "block";
                    var left = Math.round(rect.left) + "px";
                    var top = Math.round(rect.top) + "px";
                } else {
                    //if the text is empty hide existing dialog
                    menu.style.display = "none";
                }
            });
            document.addEventListener("mousedown", (e) => {
                pageX = e.pageX;
                pageY = e.pageY;
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <p>
                In today’s digital world, when there are thousands of online platforms (maybe more than that!) available over the web, it becomes quite difficult for students to opt for a quality, relevant and reliable platform for
                themselves. Meanwhile, as Computer Science is a very vast field hence students are required to find an appropriate platform that can fulfill all their needs such as – Tutorials & Courses, Placement Preparation, Interview
                Experiences, and various others. And with the same concern, GeeksforGeeks comes in the picture – a one-stop destination for all Computer Science students!!
            </p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**This is the expected output:**

[image: Expected Output]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to have a popup after selecting text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5517260/how-to-have-a-popup-after-selecting-text)

Comment: No, this doesn't help since it takes selected text based on hard-coded HTML textarea and shows up in the popup. What I asked is dynamic in any website where text can be in p,div,label etc.. I still need to get the text and show  pop-up on top of that text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `event` `clientX` and `clientY` to get the position os selected text and show dynamic pop up there. Example code is attached below. For more refer to [andreaswik](https://awik.io/get-selected-text-and-cursor-position-javascript-to-show-popup-dialog/) blog post.

**In html:**

```
<div>
       <p>
        In today’s digital world, when there are thousands of online platforms
        (maybe more than that!) available over the web, it becomes quite
        difficult for students to opt for a quality, relevant and reliable
        platform for themselves. Meanwhile, as Computer Science is a very vast
        field hence students are required to find an appropriate platform that
        can fulfill all their needs such as – Tutorials & Courses, Placement
        Preparation, Interview Experiences, and various others. And with the
        same concern, GeeksforGeeks comes in the picture – a one-stop
        destination for all Computer Science students!!
      </p>
  
    </div>
<div>
```

**In CSS file**

```
.speech-bubble {
  position: relative;
  background: #4294da;
  border-radius: .4em;
  color: white;
}

.speech-bubble:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border: 12px solid transparent;
  border-bottom-color: #4294da;
  border-top: 0;
  margin-left: -12px;
  margin-top: -12px;
}

.share-inside {
  background: url('https://awik.io/demo/js-selected-text/twicon.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 10px center;
  background-size: 24px 19px;
}

.share-inside a {
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 10px;
  padding-left: 40px;
}
```

**In js**

```
document.addEventListener('mouseup', handlerFunction, false);

// Mouse up event handler function
function handlerFunction(event) {
    
    if(document.contains(document.getElementById("share-snippet"))) {
        document.getElementById("share-snippet").remove();
    }
    
    // Check if any text was selected
    if(window.getSelection().toString().length > 0) {

        // Get selected text and encode it
        const selection = encodeURIComponent(window.getSelection().toString()).replace(/[!'()*]/g, escape);
        
        // Find out how much (if any) user has scrolled
        var scrollTop = (window.pageYOffset !== undefined) ? window.pageYOffset : (document.documentElement || document.body.parentNode || document.body).scrollTop;
        
        // Get cursor position
        const posX = event.clientX - 110;
        const posY = event.clientY + 20 + scrollTop;
      
        // Create Twitter share URL
        const shareUrl = 'http://twitter.com/share?text='+selection+'&url=https://awik.io';
        
        // Append HTML to the body, create the "Tweet Selection" dialog
        document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<div id="share-snippet" style="position: absolute; top: '+posY+'px; left: '+posX+'px;"><div class="speech-bubble"><div class="share-inside"><a href="javascript:void(0);" onClick=\'window.open(\"'+shareUrl+'\", \"\", \"menubar=no,toolbar=no,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,height=600,width=600\");\'>TWEET SELECTION</a></div></div></div>');
    }
}
```

Comment: seems, what I am looking for. Will check  this